Problem with OpenId Authorization mechanism
I’m working on a microservice architecture with the following projects: WEB, API, and AUTH. I’m encountering a problem in the WEB project where I need to retrieve the authentication token from the AUTH service.
Web project Configuration file:
Code: 
using IdentityModel.Client;
using Mango.Web;
using Mango.Web.Services;
using Mango.Web.Services.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Options;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IProductService, ProductService>();
ServiceUrls.ProductAPIBase = builder.Configuration["ServiceUrls:ProductAPI"];

builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductService, ProductService>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();


builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
})
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.Authority = builder.Configuration["ServiceUrls:IdentityAPI"];
    options.ClientId = "mango";
    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("mango");
    options.SaveTokens = true;

    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
    options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-callback-oidc";

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = "name",
        RoleClaimType = "role"
    };

    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnTokenResponseReceived = async context =>
        {
            var tokens = context.TokenEndpointResponse;
            if (tokens != null)
            {
                // Установка куки с токеном доступа
                context.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("access_token", tokens.AccessToken, new CookieOptions
                {
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    Secure = true,
                    SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
                    Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10)
                });
            }
        }
    };
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

Identity project configuration file
using Mango.Services.Identity;
using Mango.Services.Identity.Entities;
using Mango.Services.Identity.Initializer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});

builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>( options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
})
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IDbInitializer, DbInitializer>();

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
    options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
}).AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Claims.IdentityResource)
.AddInMemoryApiScopes(Claims.ApiScopes)
.AddInMemoryClients(Claims.Clients)
.AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
.AddDeveloperSigningCredential(); ;

builder.Services.AddScoped<ApplicationUser>();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var initializer = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IDbInitializer>();

var app = builder.Build();



// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
initializer.Initialize();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseIdentityServer();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

Identity project PageModel that must return me token:
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
{
    // check if we are in the context of an authorization request
    var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(Input.ReturnUrl);

    // the user clicked the "cancel" button
    if (Input.Button != "login")
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            // This "can't happen", because if the ReturnUrl was null, then the context would be null
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(Input.ReturnUrl, nameof(Input.ReturnUrl));

            // if the user cancels, send a result back into IdentityServer as if they 
            // denied the consent (even if this client does not require consent).
            // this will send back an access denied OIDC error response to the client.
            await _interaction.DenyAuthorizationAsync(context, AuthorizationError.AccessDenied);

            // we can trust model.ReturnUrl since GetAuthorizationContextAsync returned non-null
            if (context.IsNativeClient())
            {
                // The client is native, so this change in how to
                // return the response is for better UX for the end user.
                return this.LoadingPage(Input.ReturnUrl);
            }

            return Redirect(Input.ReturnUrl ?? "~/");
        }
        else
        {
            // since we don't have a valid context, then we just go back to the home page
            return Redirect("~/");
        }
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
            Input.Username, Input.Password, Input.RememberLogin, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var user = await _users.FindByNameAsync(Input.Username);

            await _events.RaiseAsync(
                new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.UserName, 
                user.Id, user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName,
                clientId: context?.Client.ClientId));


            if (context != null)    
            {
                return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, "oidc");
            }

            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(Input.ReturnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(Input.ReturnUrl);
            }

            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Input.ReturnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect("~/");
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid return Url");
            }
        }
        const string error = "invalid credentials";
        await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginFailureEvent(Input.Username, error, clientId:context?.Client.ClientId));
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, LoginOptions.InvalidCredentialsErrorMessage);
    }

    // something went wrong, show form with error
    await BuildModelAsync(Input.ReturnUrl);
    return Page();
}

And Error text:
InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'oidc'. The registered schemes are: Identity.Application, Identity.External, Identity.TwoFactorRememberMe, Identity.TwoFactorUserId, idsrv, idsrv.external. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddSomeAuthHandler?
Can somebody help me with it?
I need to implement normal authorization inside web project.
